# How can I have a enumeration on custom class?

Tags: c++, c++14

To minimize, look at the demo code:

```
const some_type A,B,C; 
// global constants with non-integral, non-POD, 
// non-trivially copyable type and is very expensive to copy
class cls{
    (const?) some_type(*&?) item;
};
```

I currently just use a map to mimic a enumeration, but it seems to be rather slow.What I want is to ensure that `item` in `class cls` is one of the `A,B,C` above, preferably statically, and enhance the performance. (It seems returning from map would cause the map to change state or at least make some change that was slow per profiling)

I tried to use a enumeration on custom class, but it complains that the underlying type must be integral type. It should be possible that use a `reinterpret_cast` of pointers as a work around, but still, it shouldn't be the decent way to do so, right?

Any suggestions?

Comment: you want a compilation error if `item`'s type is not `some_type` ? or what? `A`, `B`, `C` are values , not types. Maybe it would help to show some real code that you want to disallow

Comment: probably a `bool operator==(const cls& other)`. That way, you can check whatever values you want A. B or C to have.

Comment: How "ensure" do you want it to be?

Comment: @NicolBolas, it may preferably be a compile-time check, or to prevent further instantiation. I think Racicot's solution would work but haven't tried it.

Comment: @YiFei: I guess my point is this: using a regular `enum` type (or an `enum class`, to me, "ensures" that the value will only be one of the enumerators. Does it *guarantee* it? No. But it does mean that you'd have to use `static_cast`s to get around it. An `enum` prevents accidental misuse, not *perfidy*.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yeah, but `enum` by standard don't provide support for custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the constructor of `some_type` private to allow only one class to construct that type.

The *enum* will be implemented in that very class:

```
struct some_type {
    // Making copy and move constructor deleted will
    // prevent the creation of any other instances.
    some_type(some_type&&) = delete;
    some_type(const some_type&) = delete;
    some_type& operator=(some_type&&) = delete;
    some_type& operator=(const some_type&) = delete;

    // The `enum`
    static some_type A, B, C;

private:
    // The constructor is private here, only us can construct the type.
    some_type() = default;
};

some_type some_type::A;
some_type some_type::B;
some_type some_type::C;
```

Here in later code, you can't create or copy instances of this class.
So your type `cls` will use the only existing instances of the program:

```
struct cls {
    cls(const some_type& item_) : item{item_} {}

    const some_type& item;
};

int main() {
    // Working!
    cls myCls{some_type::A};

    // error there, trying to create a new instance that is not A, B or C
    //cls myCls2{some_type{}};
}
```

Comment: Care to add how to use those instances in a `switch`?

Comment: Switch work with integral values only. You should be able to use it by comparing pointers. Although I'd recommend to not use a switch there, as it more or less a workaround for a design flaw.

Comment: Hmmm... what about a cast operator to an integral?

Comment: Sounds like a good way to obfuscate your own code! The best would be to implement the logic in the `some_type` class and avoid the switch altogether.

Comment: OP didn't ask for switches. You could use integral conversion if the operator can be evaluated as a constant expression, but I'm not sure.